# twitterizer API Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter, twitterizer

I am using Twitterizer API for accessing twitter related functionality. I have one demo application that works fine with my consumerkey and consumersecret i run this application locally. but when i integrate the same settings in my live application i got this error

**Value cannot be null.Parameter name: String**

Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check you keys. Also check your server time. Sometimes timestamp that we generate give some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Without a stacktrace or more details, there is absolutely no way I could give you an absolutely accurate answer.

My best guess is that your request is failing, possibly because of DNS, lack of .NET permissions, or misconfigured proxy settings on the server and you're not checking if the ResponseObject is null before trying to use it.

To check for failed requests at runtime (so you can display a nice error without an ugly try/catch), check the `Result` property of the `TwitterResponse<T>` you got back from the library.

For example,

```cs
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
tokens.AccessToken = "XXX";
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "XXX";
tokens.ConsumerKey = "XXX";
tokens.ConsumerSecret = "XXX";

TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, "Hello, #Twitterizer");
if (tweetResponse.Result == RequestResult.Success)
{
    // Tweet posted successfully!
}
else
{
    // Something bad happened
}
```

That code is lifted directly from [my homepage](http://www.twitterizer.net/).

Comment: in this code what is tokens.AccessToken and tokens.AccessTokenScrete?

Comment: Before you can post updates to Twitter, the user must authorize your account using OAuth. When they do, your application will get the access token and secret values.

Comment: exactly, i am getting error in authentication.i am using following code                                                    OAuthTokenResponse requestToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken("consumerKey", "consumerScrete", callbackUrl); and getting the error.

Comment: Are you getting the response token first? Then, is the user logging in to twitter and granting your application access? These MUST happen before you request an access token.

Comment: Ricky, can you please provide me steps? Actually i downloaded the code from your site and trying to implement in my web application. Also i followed instructions mentioned on your pages. Thanks